# Can you have a nested argument in a function in R?

Tags: r

Is it possible to have something like this in R?

```
plotFunction <- function(gradientCols(x,y)){

p <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = x, high = y) +
  geom_bin2d()
return(p)
}

plotFunction(gradientCols("red","blue"))
```

Where the argument `gradientCols` in the function `plotFunction` can take 2 additional arguments (i.e., `x`,`y`)?
Or is there a better way to do this without having to explicitly state all the individual arguments in the function?

Comment: What is `gradientCols` function? Inside your `plotFunction`, it is not used.  If the intention is to pass those variable `function(x, y){ ggplot(diamondds, aes(carat, price)) + scale_fill_gradient(low = {{x}}, high = {{y}}) + geom_bin2d()}; plotFunction(red, blue)`

Comment: the gradientCols would be used for the ```scale_fill_gradient``` values of ```low=x``` and ```high=y```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we just pass the 'x' and 'y'

```
library(ggplot2)
plotFunction <- function(x, y){ 
      ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price)) + 
         scale_fill_gradient(low = x, high = y) +
         geom_bin2d()};

plotFunction("red", "blue")
```